# pandas : reverse of a crosstab

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like the following
[image]

I have a code to do crosstab

```
print(pd.crosstab(mypd['a'],mypd['b'],mypd['c']))
```

and gives
[image]

what's the revers of crosstab , and maybe give back column a,b and c ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) by counts and then [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(mypd['a'], [mypd['b'],mypd['c']])

s = df.stack([0,1])

new = s.index.repeat(s).to_frame(index=False)
```

**Sample**:

```
print (mypd)
     a    b      c  d
0  foo  one   dull  1
1  foo  one   dull  2
2  foo  one  shiny  3


df = pd.crosstab(mypd['a'], [mypd['b'],mypd['c']])
print (df)
b    one      
c   dull shiny
a             
foo    2     1

s = df.stack([0,1])
print (s)
a    b    c    
foo  one  dull     2
          shiny    1
dtype: int64

new = s.index.repeat(s).to_frame(index=False)
print (new)
     a    b      c
0  foo  one   dull
1  foo  one   dull
2  foo  one  shiny
```